# Android NDK: enabling pretty print when debugging Android native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, pretty-print, ndk-gdb

When debugging Android native code, it's quite a mess when you want to see things inside c++ containers(like std::vector), I know there is pretty print, but how to integrate it with Android native code debugging?